# resize multiple images while uploading

Tags: php, image, upload, resize

Hi im trying to resize multiple image while uploading i have the function that resize but its only work for one image so please can anyone shom me how to loop this for multiple file upload

```
if( $_FILES['image']['size']< $max_file_size ){
    // get file extension
    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
//  $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['files']['name'][$f], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if (in_array($ext, $valid_exts)) {
        /* resize image */

        foreach ($sizes as $w => $h) {

            $files[] = resize($w, $h);

                        }

    } else {
        $msg = 'Unsupported file';
    }
} else{
    $msg = 'Please upload image smaller than 200KB';
}
```

Comment: Have a look at what the $_FILES array actually looks like. $_FILES['image']['size'][0] will be the first image. Increment the 0. I don't see a loop so hard to give a good answer.

Comment: this is where i got this if you wanna take alook at it thx http://source.w3bees.com/resize-image-while-uploading.html

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but might give you an idea.
The way this works is by looping through all of the $_FILES of the variable `$iname` which is 'image'. I set this since it's used multiple times, so if you ever change it, its easier.

I create a new variable called `$image` which will be the variables for that specific image. I do this by looping through all of the variables of `$_FILES[$iname]`. I set the `$image` variable to the `$key` and the new value, which will be an array. We reference the correct array using the `$i` variable.

Next I simply use your existing code. Since the `resize()` function only calls for width and height, I am unsure what happens here. Another parameter should be passed to reference the image you want to resize, which will be `$image`.

From the visible code I typed, not knowing what `resize()` is, this code is insecure. You should really check more than just the file extension since it can easily be changed. I usually use exif to check the image header. I also never store the data users upload unless I re-encode it using a GDI function in PHP.

Hopefully this will get you started.

```
$i = 0;
$iname = 'image';
for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES[$iname]['size']); $i++) {

   // Create new Image Array
   $image = array();
   foreach($_FILES[$iname] as $key => $val) {
     $image[$key] = $val[$i];
   }


   if( $image['size'] < $max_file_size ) {
      $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
      if (in_array($ext, $valid_exts)) {
         foreach ($sizes as $w => $h) {
            // How is resize getting the $_FILES?
            // Should pass a variable of $image and use it instead
            $files[] = resize($w, $h);
         }
      } else {
        $msg = 'Unsupported file';
       }
    } else{
       $msg = 'Please upload image smaller than 200KB';
    }
}
```